# How to extract all smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

My goal is to find greedy, prodigal, and suicidal smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain. Is there any trick that by using that I could extract all smart contracts on Ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get an Ethereum node
2. Walk all mined Ethereum blocks from genesis block `1` - to `latest` you can e.g. use Web3.py or Web3.js to interact with your node API
3. Check all transactions in a block - use `web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock`
4. If the transaction is a contract deployment transaction you have your smart contract

Comment: \What is the best way to decompile EVM bytecodes to Solidity code in that process?

Comment: Please open this as a separate question - I recommend asking on ethereum.stackexchange.com